# Conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

Why do the compiler complain about casting here

```
 class DBconnection {
  public:
     DataSet* query(string qStr) {
     ConnImpl* conImpl = ConnectionPool::getInstance()->acquireConnection();
     DataSet *data = new DataSet();
     conImpl->doQuery(qStr,data);
     ConnectionPool::getInstance()->releaseConnection(conImpl);
     return data;
 }
};


 class Client {
  public:
     DataSet* queryDB(string q) {
     return new DBconnection()->query(q);
  }
 };
```

The Client::queryDB(std:::string) is actually returning a DataSet pointer through DBconnection::query(std::string).

The error:

error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'DBconnection *' to 'DataSet *'
    Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

If I try for instance - c-casting, it doesnt work either

```
 return new (DataSet*)DBconnection()->query(q);
```

Comment: Your code should work. Is this your real code? In your last line, the placement of the cast is wrong. It must be before `new`, otherwise, this is placement-new syntax. However, no cast should be necessary. If the function returns a `DataSet*`, then you do not have to cast it to `DataSet*`. (Side note: Your code leaks all objects it creates)

Comment: @gexicide - Yes It must work since my professor in computer science made it :-). So I cannot understand why the compiler complains or why he is wrong? About the last line- this is what I've tried with :-)

Comment: By the way, I don't know about the environment you code in, but in most C++ environments calling `Client::queryDB` with your current code will create a leak. You could both fix the leak and the problem in your question by simply removing the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten your operator precedence table:

`return (new DBconnection())->query(q);`

will work. `new` has a lower precedence than `->`.